# Como remover espaçamento entre tag main e header? (resolvido)

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Quando coloco um elemento **h2** dentro da tag **section** que é filha da **main**, *aparece um espaçamento* em branco entre o *main e o header*. **O problema também ocorre caso a tag h2 seja colocada dentro da tag main.**

```css
html,
body,
main {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/* INICIO CABEÇALHO */

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.5em;
}

#navbar {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar-div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar-spam {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 25em;
  height: 3.5em;
}

#navbar-logo {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: teal;
  margin-right: 40rem;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: springgreen;
  margin-left: 25em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.5em;
}


/* INICIO CORPO DO SITE */

main {
  height: 300rem;
  background-color: brown;
  color: black;
}

#secao1,
#secao2,
#secao3,
#secao4,
#secao5 {
  height: 20%;
}


/* INICIO RODAPÉ */

footer {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #ffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <div id="navbar-div">
        <span id="navbar-spam">
                    <h1 id="navbar-logo">
                        logo
                    </h1>
                </span>
        <div id="menu">
          menu
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section id="secao1">
      <h2>Seção 1</h2>
    </section>
    <section id="secao2">
      Seção 2
    </section>
    <section id="secao3">
      Seção 3
    </section>
    <section id="secao4">
      Seção 4
    </section>
    <section id="secao5">
      Seção 5
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    rodapé
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema adicionando o 'h2' junto do main, body e html no documento style.css.
Para que o h2 funcione corretamente, removi o font-size.

Answer (score -1):

Altere main,body,html por *

Da na mesma, pois * seleciona todos os elementos, seria o mesmo que definir o body todo, o html todo, o main todo, e todos os itens, ao inves de 1 por 1, com *, vc seleciona todos de vez.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica <3